# Is there a replacement of VM option -XX:+EnableSharedLookupCache after Java 8?

Tags: java

I want to improve the performance of an application that does numerous calls to `ClassLoader::getResource()`. I found that VM option `-XX:+EnableSharedLookupCache` but it is no longer supported after JAVA 8. What should I use instead ?

Comment: Can you confirm, e.g. from profiling, that the performance problems you experience are indeed caused by `ClassLoader::getResource()`?

Comment: yes indeed it was showing in the top of hotspot methods in visual vm

Comment: You could load the resources once and then cache them in a Map in the code.